# Error code 20545 Crystal Reports when printing

Tags: printing, crystal-reports, vb6, report

I'm printing a report, created in Crystal Reports 6.0 from VB6 application. Sometimes the users get an error 20545 ("request was cancelled by the user"). They do not click "Cancel" button and printer exists on the machine (it's a network printer and it's working properly). Can anybody suggest, what's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://dotnetbutchering.blogspot.com/2008/05/crystal-reports-request-canceled-by.html?_sm_au_=i7H2DFFpf154WqWF) link the default printer may be unavailable.  Other places I've encountered while googling your problem say that it might be a database issue and restarting the server(s), but you're stating that they are NOT cancelling the print jobs and trying a second time, so that's not as likely.